# How to extract data from the points closer to required location in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, data-extraction

I have two `data.frame`. `FakeData` has the `Long & Lat` along with data while `ExCor` has `Long & Lat` of the points that I would like to have the data extracted from `FakeData`. `ExCor` should only extract data from the closest points.
Here is some sample data to start with

```
rm(list = ls())

DF1 = data.frame(t(data.frame(Grids = 1:5, Long = runif(5, min = 5, max = 10), Lat = runif(5, min = 2, max = 3))))
DF2 = data.frame(X1 = runif(1095, 0.5,1), X2 = runif(1095, 1.5,2), X3 = runif(1095, 0.5,1.5), X4 = runif(1095, 0.5,6), X5 = runif(1095, 0.5,15))
FakeData = rbind(DF1, DF2)

ExCor = data.frame(t(data.frame(Long = runif(3, 7, 9), Lat = runif(3, 2,3))))
```

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Is the example correct?  The first 3 row names for 'FakeData' are `Grids`, `Long`, and `Lat`

Comment: @arkun, I corrected the `ExCor` data frame. I would need to populate this data frame with data from `FakeData` having either matching `Long & Lat` or grabing data from the closest  `FakeData` `Long and lat` point. Does this make sense?

Comment: So for each point in DF2 find the nearest point in DF1? Try the FNN package.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, I will look into the package for my future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many ways to achieve this is to use the `st_nearest_feature` predicate within `sf::st_join`. First, though, you need to rejig your data structure so that it is more compatible with the packages that work with spatial geometries.

```
library(sf)

# Reshape datasets so that coords and attributes are columns, not rows
ExCor <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, ExCor), row.names(ExCor))
FakeData <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, FakeData), row.names(FakeData))

# Convert to sf objects
FakeData_sf <- st_as_sf(FakeData, coords=c('Long', 'Lat'))
ExCor_sf <- st_as_sf(ExCor, coords=c('Long', 'Lat'))

# Spatial join nearest feature
newdat <- st_join(ExCor_sf, FakeData_sf, join=st_nearest_feature)
```

You can then write out to a .csv again if you want...

```
st_write(newdat, 'newdat.csv', layer_options='GEOMETRY=AS_XY')
```

Comment: Thanks @jbaums, is there an easy option to `transpose` the `newdat` before saving as `CSV`